# Using Retrofit for Google's custom search via Google's REST API

Tags: android, rest, google-api, retrofit

I've made an app that has a search function that is set to search from a custom Google search I made (using their Custom Search service). This doesn't have a Java library, so I'm using Retrofit to request using the REST API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest), however I've run into a problem:

Retrofit is working fine, but the request always returns a 400 error with the following information:
*"domain": "usageLimits",    "reason": "keyInvalid"*

The API key I use in the request is the Android application key for my project in Google dev console. I assume this doesn't work however because Retrofit doesn't let Google know that I'm sending the request from my app?

What are the possible fixes for this situation?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've confirmed that my APK is signed with the correct keys, and I triplequadruplequintuple-everything checked the SHA1 used to generate the apikey. I've generated a new api key about 3 or 4 times to see if that fixes it.

### EDIT2:

**I got it to work!**

You don't make an Android API key (it does not work with this), you make a browser API key, in which you set the allowed referers to all (potentially dangerous).

You use that API key to request using Retrofit. I feel like this should be noted by Google: no doubt many would assume Android app? -> Android API key - but that is only the case when Google has made a library for the API.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you simply need to pass the key as a query parameter into your rest interface.

As an example, if you wanted to execute this GET command below

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures`

Then you interface would be declared like so

```
public interface RestApi {
    GET ("/customsearch/v1")
    Response customSearch(@Query("key") String key, @Query("cx") String cx, @Query("q") String query);
}
```

Then you can execute the call like so

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
  .setEndpoint("https://www.googleapis.com")
  .build();
RestApi restApi = restAdapter.create(RestApi.class)
restApi.customSearch("INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY", "017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve", "lectures");
```

Now don't forget to replace the INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY with your key that you've generated from the Google Dev Console.

Comment: I've got my app setup to do just that since the beginning, but the response is always this same error.

Comment: Make sure you api key is correct.  Also change the log level (.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)) on your RestAdapter and verify that the final url is valid.  Also I would suggest you take a different rest client and attempt the call with the same values to verify if you get the same result or not.

Comment: I've "partially solved" my issue, I'm now using a browser api key (that allows every sort of referer), but now Google tells me my key is expired (it isn't)

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with the key or how it's used.  Can you generate a new one?  Unfortunately I've never actually use that rest api before, I'm not familiar with it so this is as far as I can go.  Maybe some else can help.

Comment: I've solved my own problem by experimenting with the Dev console (see my edit). Thanks for your help though! :)